# How can I get a list of first parent commits using git python?

Tags: gitpython

I'd like to run the equivalent of this command from git python, but have not been able to figure out a way to accomplish this.

```
git rev-list --first-parent commit1..HEAD
```

I'm looking to get the result of that command into an iterable of git python's Commit objects. I tried repo.iter_commits but it doesn't appear to be capable of taking in arguments to rev-list that don't take parameters.

My use case is that "commit1" will be the commit upon which a branch was based, and I'll run this code while the branch is checked out. Thus, this command would give me the list of commits committed to the branch, even in the presence of merge commits from the branch "commit1" is on.

I have also tried

```
repo.iter_commits('HEAD ^commit1')
```

but that results in the following error:
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git rev-list HEAD ^commit1 --
  stderr: 'fatal: bad revision 'HEAD ^commit1'

However, I can run

```
git rev-list HEAD ^commit1 --
```

in bash and it runs fine. And besides, the command doesn't really give me what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get what I needed by working directly with the commit's parents list in git python. Here is a snippet of what worked for me:

```
       commits = list() 
       c = repo.head.commit
       while (True):         
            firstparent = c.parents[0]
            if (firstparent != commit1):
                c = firstparent
                commits.append(c)
            else:
                break
```

The above code does not handle first commits (which have no parents.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
repo.iter_commits(repo.head.commit, first_parent=True)
```

(I'm working with git python version 3.1.29).